# Missing Searchbar API for firefox quantum

Tags: api, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, searchbar

Since firefox Quantum a lot of extension doesm't work anymore. One of them is the "add to Searchbar" extension. I searched in the firefox quantum Webextension API's after a solution to develop a new extension to add searchengines to the default searchinputfield. But it seems there is no api access to the searchengines list for reading or editing this List. And there is no posibility to replace the default searchbar because, you only can add a button to the toolbar. see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface. 
Is there any possbility to get access to the searchbar? And  if not where can I make a feauture Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is not yet possible.

You are looking for these feature requests:

Add APIs to manage search engines for the web search bar/location bar
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268401

Add an API to list installed search engines
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1352598

Please follow those bugs to keep up to date with the progress that is being made.